# Store multiple strings in a char array in C

Tags: c

Today I saw a usage of **char in C** as followed:

```
    const char temp[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                        "Host:www.google.com\r\n"
                        "\r\n";
```

At first, I thought there would be a compile error, but actually it passed the compilation!
So can someone please tell me why it can work?
I am a fresh man learning C programming.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Adding how you compiled and with what would likely help this question, and the answer.

Comment: you try to put ";" at the end.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to type it here...But in my code, it does exists.

Answer (score 6):

If to place the missed semicolon at the end then this statement

```
const char temp[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n"
                    "Host:www.google.com\r\n"
                    "\r\n";
```

is equivalent to

```
const char temp[] = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
```

According to the C Standard in the section where translation phases are described there is written

**6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated**

Sometines it is convinient to split a long string literal that does not fit a line into several shorter adjacent literals.

Comment: Thanks so much and I did have a semicolon in my code, I forgot to type it here...Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
const char str[] = "stringstringstring";

const char str[] = "string" "string" "string";

const char str[] = "string"
              "string"
              "string";

#define NAME "string"
const char str[] = "string" NAME "string";
```

Will all have the same result. C concatenates adjacent strings.

Answer (score 1):

C has [**string literal concatenation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal_concatenation#String_literal_concatenation), meaning that adjacent string literals are concatenated at compile time; this allows long strings to be split over multiple lines, and also allows string literals resulting from C preprocessor defines and macros to be appended to strings at compile time.

For instance:

```
printf(__FILE__ ": %d: Hello "
       "world\n", __LINE__);
```

will expand to

```
printf("helloworld.c" ": %d: Hello "
       "world\n", 10);
```

which is syntactically equivalent to

```
printf("helloworld.c: %d: Hello world\n", 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a single string consisting of multiple concatenated string literals. The C language allows string literals that appear next to each other without any operator in between to be concatenated to form a single string. This is useful for string constants that span multiple lines of source, as you've seen. It's also useful when a preprocessor macro defines a string literal, you can write something like

```
#define BALANCE_FMT "%5.2f"
printf("Your balance is: " BALANCE_FMT "\n", balance);
```